# How to entirely disable keyboard shortcuts for "kiosk mode" applications

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, compiz, kiosk

I am trying to develop a "kiosk mode" application based on the Chromium CEF web browser.  I want to prevent the user from leaving the browser.  This entails disabling keyboard shortcuts such as (but not limited to) the following:

- Alt-F4
- Ctrl-Super-D
- Ctrl-Alt-Del
- Super-S

I currently have a script that, prior to starting my app, uses **xmodmap** to load in a special keymap and mouse pointer configuration.  It also uses **gsettings** to set various keys within the following:

- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
- org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings

Under Ubuntu 14.04, this approach seems to work for most keys, but it is very cumbersome.  Furthermore, ot all keys seem to be accounted for under Ubuntu 12.04.  I may have to set keys here:

- /apps/metacity/window_keybindings/close
- /apps/compiz-1/plugins/core/screen0/options/close_window_key

How can I make this completely work under both Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04?  Is this even the right approach?  Is there perhaps an easier way than setting each individual key?  I thought using **xmodmap** would work best, but it appears that the OS intercepts some keystrokes prior to them reaching my app.

Comment: If I want to quit an app, and it "won't allow me" I kill it at once. And then erase it. It's not app author's (nor is it yours @gonzobrains)  place to tell me I can't exit the app when I need to (my computer, my circumstances, my usage scenario - can you know them all?).

Comment: umm.  i did say "kiosk mode" application, right?  *ding*  google it.

Comment: Darn. You did and I missed it. Comment irrelevant then.